# Swift - Optional Binding doesn't show UIAlertController

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, uialertview, option-type

I have created a helper function to check the values of NSUserDefaults by using optional binding. I want to use this function to confirm values exist before executing any code in an IBAction.

```
    func checkProfile() {
    //optional binding to confirm that some strings (even empty string values), have been saved to user defaults. Will not face error when unwrapping the optionals on webView or MFMailComposer. Checking Title, FirstName, SecondName

    if let titleString: String = userDefaults.stringForKey("title") {
        //confirmed that there is a string value for titleString
        println("there is a string value for titleString \(titleString)")

        if let firstNameString: String = userDefaults.stringForKey("firstName") {
            //confirmed that there is a string value for firstName

            if let secondNameString: String = userDefaults.stringForKey("secondName") {
                //confirmed that there is a string value for secondName

            } else {
                //secondNameString missing, show alert
                var alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Profile data incomplete", message: "Please provide your 'Profile' data to continue.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
                    //"action in" casts this closure as a type of UIAlertAction which is required by the addAction property.
                    action in self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
                    //"return" provides the -> Void return type, as not including would return a type of closure (above)
                    return
                }))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else {
            //FirstNameString missing, show alert
            var alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Profile data incomplete", message: "Please provide your 'Profile' data to continue.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
                //"action in" casts this closure as a type of UIAlertAction which is required by the addAction property.
                action in self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
                //"return" provides the -> Void return type, as not including would return a type of closure (above)
                return
            }))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    } else {
        //titleString missing, show alert
        var alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Profile data incomplete", message: "Please provide your 'Profile' data to continue.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
            //"action in" casts this closure as a type of UIAlertAction which is required by the addAction property.
            action in self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
            //"return" provides the -> Void return type, as not including would return a type of closure (above)
            return
        }))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's a fairly straight forward check for 3 stored string values, that return a UIAlertController if any of them are missing.

When implementing this function at the beginning of an IBAction (user clicks on a button), it exhibits some strange behaviour.

Depending on an unrelated value stored in NSUserDefaults, the IBAction will either perform a segue to another ViewController; or it will implement an instance of another class, and perform a function that will generate a PDF file.

When the value is set so that the IBAction will eventually perform the segue, I can see that the optional binding works as expected and returns the UIAlertView if one of the 3 stored values = nil (prior to performing the segue).

However, when it is set so that the PDF will be generated, it seem's to ignore the `checkProfile()` function completely. (will not even println to console at any point).

This is resulting in a run-time error later as I find nil when unwrapping the optional value I am wanting check in `checkProfile()` - Are there any reasons why this function will run correctly prior to performing a segue, but not before implementing a class instance? I see no logical reason for this behaviour at the moment.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the IBAction where the function is getting called:

```
@IBAction func claimButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject){
//Saves more values to userDefaualts
userDefaults.setObject(dateOfJourneyTextField.text, forKey: "dateOfJourney")


checkTickets()
checkProfile()

//if function to check the ticket type
if userDefaults.stringForKey("ticketType") != "Annual" {
    //calls the function to create the PDF prior to attempting to load the Mail Composer View where it will be an attachment
    let composePaperClaim = ComposePaperClaim()
    composePaperClaim.generatePDF(self)

    //loads MFMailComposeViewContoller...

} else {
    //Does not require PDF, perform Segue to take to the WebView
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showWebViewSegue", sender: self)
}
```

}

It is in the call to `composePaperClaim.generatePDF(self)` when I see the error as this tries to unwrap `userDefaults.stringForKey("title")!` which I had tried to establish already had a value through optional binding.

Comment: I have no idea how to fix the issue, but you do not need to specify the type like `var alert : UIAlertController`, this can be determined by inference, also the alert can be constant, using `let alert = UIAlertController(...` same thing goes for the `userDefaults.stringForKey`

Comment: It sounds like you need to show the code that is calling this code as well, that is probably where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling this `checkProfile()` function but doing nothing with the result. That function should be returning a boolean or something to prevent the calling function from proceeding any further. What you're going to get is a mess of pushed view controllers on top of presented view controllers and then into some strange state.

At the moment you'll be calling that PDF generation function whatever happens in your `checkProfile`, as long as the type isn't annual. This presumably presents another view controller on top of the alert, which you don't see, and then you're probably assuming a value is present in one of the things you're checking for in the `checkProfile` function.

Comment: Looks to have worked, the function now returns a Bool which halts the code execution of the IBAction with a simple if statement! Thank you for your help!